# exclude category from wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to exclude category from shoowing my blog posts. My category id is **62**. category name is **perfect_work**

Here is my wordpress blog template code:

```
    <div id="left" class="eleven columns">

    <?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('paged='.$paged);
    ?>

    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <div class="title">

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <div class="postmeta">  <span>by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> | <span><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?></span> | <span><?php the_category(', '); ?></span> </div>

            </div>

            <div class="entry">

            <?php $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'top_feature'); ?>    

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_attr[0]; ?>" class="postim scale-with-grid" id="blog-thumb" ></a>
                <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_archive', ''); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php getpagenavi(); ?>
    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
</div>
```

I already tried using

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query('cat=-62');
```

its not work. I also put

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-62'); ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Its work but page navigation not work, and also not showing others post. only 1st 5 post show.

Any Solution?

Comment: You know that you can pass more than 1 parameter to `WP_Query` function right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the page number

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Then you may use

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query('cat=-62&paged=' . $paged);
```

Or use

```
$cat_id = get_cat_ID('perfect_work');
$wp_query = new WP_Query('cat=-' . $cat_id . '&paged=' . $paged);
```

Then loop

```
if($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        // ...
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I just used: $wp_query->query('cat=-62&paged='.$paged); Its works perfect. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one you have to specify the `showposts` to limit the posts

```
<?php $wp_query->set( 'cat', '-62' ); ?>
<?php query_posts( 'showposts=10' ); ?> 
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?> 
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

.
.
.
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Note : The minus sign indicates the exclusion of all Posts which
>   belong to that category from being retrieved from the database. In
>   turn, the Loop will never have Posts of that category id and only
>   process the specified number of Posts of other category ids.

Comment: I know about minus and also know how to exclude it. but its not works. anyway, already got the answer. Thanks for try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the codex on [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), it is imo very detailed, look at the [category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) params part

Just add a minus sign `-` in front of the categories you dont want, so the below code would mean show posts with category 10 and 11, but exclude category 62

```
$recent = new WP_Query("showposts=3&cat=10,11,-62")
```

Comment: I think the OP knows that because he tried, the problem seems to be other

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `$temp` variable before or after the query. You should use something like this:

```
//This should do the trick
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'cat' => -62,
    'paged' => $paged
);

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <!-- the loop -->
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <!-- end of the loop -->

  <!-- pagination here -->
  //The real trick!
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Two things to note:

- The paged query parameter
- To reset the query use `wp_reset_postdata()`

Comment: Thanks for your tricks. But its not work. Anyway, I got the solutions from "Recovering Since 2003" answer.

Comment: @NoDiv_NoClass: I think is the same solution

Comment: Functionally yes, but its not work in my blog when I used it using $args 

I don't know why, but I think there is some problem with blog codes. 

Anyway, I'm really not a expert in php

Comment: @NoDiv_NoClass: Is exactly the same thing my friend, you can pass the argument as string or array. `WP_Query` function parse both.